# Invocation error

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I am trying to run the script task but its giving me an error

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Below is the script task that I executed

```
       using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
#endregion

namespace ST_dc84f0f0b249439e95ab14b5ecae9d04
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    /// or parent of this class.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
        /* To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
         * either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
         * the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
         * code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
         * Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
         * ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
         * To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.
         * 
         * Example of reading from a variable:
         *  DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of writing to a variable:
         *  Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";
         * 
         * Example of reading from a package parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;
         *  
         * Example of reading from a project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
         * */

        #endregion

        #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
        /* This script task can fire events for logging purposes.
         * 
         * Example of firing an error event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0);
         * 
         * Example of firing an information event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain)
         * 
         * Example of firing a warning event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0);
         * */
        #endregion

        #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
        /* Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
         * "Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.
         * 
         * Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  SqlConnection myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         *
         * Example of using a File connection manager
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  string filePath = (string)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         * */
        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
        /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
        /// To open Help, press F1.
        /// </summary>
        public void Main()
        {

            //Declare Variables
            string SourceFolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::SourceFolderPath"].Value.ToString();
            string DestinationFolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::DestinationFolderPath"].Value.ToString();
            string FileExtension = Dts.Variables["User::FileExtension"].Value.ToString();
            string FileDelimiter = Dts.Variables["User::FileDelimiter"].Value.ToString();
            string CreateTableStatement = "";
            string ColumnList = "";

            //Reading file names one by one
            string SourceDirectory = SourceFolderPath;
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory, "*" + FileExtension);
            foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            {
                // do something with fileName
                //MessageBox.Show(fileName);

                //Read first line(Header) and prepare Create Statement for Excel Sheet
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
                string filenameonly = (((fileName.Replace(SourceDirectory, "")).Replace(FileExtension, "")).Replace("\\", ""));
                CreateTableStatement = (" Create Table [" + filenameonly + "] ([" + file.ReadLine().Replace(FileDelimiter, "] Text,[")) + "] Text)";
                file.Close();
                //MessageBox.Show(CreateTableStatement.ToString());


                //Construct ConnectionString for Excel
                string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + DestinationFolderPath + "\\" + filenameonly
                    + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"";
                OleDbConnection Excel_OLE_Con = new OleDbConnection();
                OleDbCommand Excel_OLE_Cmd = new OleDbCommand();



                //drop Excel file if exists
                File.Delete(DestinationFolderPath + "\\" + filenameonly + ".xlsx");
                Excel_OLE_Con.ConnectionString = connstring;
                Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
                Excel_OLE_Cmd.Connection = Excel_OLE_Con;

                //Use OLE DB Connection and Create Excel Sheet
                Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = CreateTableStatement;
                Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //Writing Data of File to Excel Sheet in Excel File
                int counter = 0;
                string line;

                System.IO.StreamReader SourceFile =
                new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
                while ((line = SourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (counter == 0)
                    {
                        ColumnList = "[" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "],[") + "]";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string query = "Insert into [" + filenameonly + "] (" + ColumnList + ") VALUES('" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "','") + "')";
                        // MessageBox.Show(query.ToString());
                        var command = query;
                        Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = command;
                        Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                Excel_OLE_Con.Close();
                SourceFile.Close();
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
        }



        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Error in the log file is

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Cannot update. 
>   Database or object is read-only.    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()    at
>   ST_95d12bd810fe43d993a0b7a913fec230.ScriptMain.Main()

Comment: the issue is clear `Database or object is read-only` and the solution is provided as an answer, why not [accepting](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) it?

Comment: Sorry Hadi for the late response. I was travelling for my work purpose.  I really appreciate your time and help. Thanks!

Comment: Just remove this property. You can do this by code (assuming strFilePath is the excel path)

System.IO.File.SetAttributes(strFilePath, System.IO.FileAttributes.Normal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error log it look like your excel file is readonly.

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.

Just remove this property. You can do this by code (assuming `strFilePath` is the excel path)

```
System.IO.File.SetAttributes(strFilePath, System.IO.FileAttributes.Normal)
```